# How to map collection with entity from another context in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've this EF entity

```
    public class Show
    {
        private ICollection<Country> _allowedCountries;

        public virtual ICollection<Country> AllowedCountries
        {
            get { return _allowedCountries ?? (_allowedCountries = new List<Country>()); }
            set { _allowedCountries = value; }

        }

}
```

where Country is entity from another Context.

When I am trying read property AllowedCountries I get error about no existing table.

Table 'db1.countries' doesn't exist

Show is mapped to db1.show table and Country is mapped to db2.countries

My Mapping Country and Show tables

```
    public class CountryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
    {
        public CountryMap()
        {
            ToTable("countries", "db2");

//other non useful information

        }
    }

        public ShowMap()
        {
            ToTable("shows", "db1");

          HasMany(x => x.AllowedCountries) //I think problem here
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("allowed_countries");
                    m.MapLeftKey("ShowID");
                    m.MapRightKey("CountryID");
                });
}
```

I think that problem has been caused by incorrect mapping AllowedCountries

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have related entities from different contexts. You might consider using a Linked Server (MS SQL feature) to make both tables visible to one connection.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you should avoid this kind of mess. Maybe you should ask yourself why you have two contexts.

In general you should open a context from the moment you need it and close it when you are done; and everything in between is done in a unit of work.